# mybatis using dynamic sql foreach

Tags: java, mybatis

How to use `foreach` in mybatis mapper? I mean what parameters I should send there?

For example I've got this select statement

```
<select id="findObjectsWithIds" resultMap="SimpleObjectResult">
    SELECT * FROM testschema."XSimpleTable"
    WHERE ID in
    <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list" 
        open="(" separator="," close=")">
            #{item}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

I've got interface with method

```
List<SimpleObject> findObjectsWithIds(List<String> ids);
```

I've got implementation of the interface

```
@Override
public List<SimpleObject> findObjectsWithIds(List<String> ids) {
    SqlSession sqlSession = MyBatisSqlSessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
        SimpleMapper simpleMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(SimpleMapper.class);
        return simpleMapper.findObjectsWithIds(ids);
    } finally {
        sqlSession.close();
    }
}
```

And when I make an attempt to run - I've got this error

[image]

How to use `foreach` properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved.

I added annotation `param`

```
List<SimpleObject> findObjectsWithIds(@Param("list") List<Integer> ids);
```

And also I sent `String` representation of indices instead of `Integer`.